# JMSTemplate Bean not found - Autowire doesn't work

Tags: azure, javabeans, autowired, spring-jms

It worked fine yesterday and suddenly it doesn't work anymore. I didn't change anything tho. I am new to JMS and followed this tutorial: [Tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/java/spring-framework/configure-spring-boot-starter-java-app-with-azure-service-bus?tabs=use-a-service-bus-queue)

I just want to send and receive Messages with the Azure Service Bus.

**Error Message:**

```
Field jmsTemplate in com.example.messagesender.MessageSenderApplication required a bean of type 'org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
    - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)
```

**Action:**

Consider defining a bean of type 'org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate' in your configuration.

**Pom.xml:**

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.azure.spring</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-azure-starter-servicebus-jms</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.0-beta.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.azure</groupId>
            <artifactId>azure-messaging-servicebus</artifactId>
            <version>7.14.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>RELEASE</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-jms -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jms</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.jms/javax.jms-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.jms-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.messaginghub</groupId>
            <artifactId>pooled-jms</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.azure.spring</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-azure-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>5.3.0</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
```

**Java File:**

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableJms
public class MessageSenderApplication implements CommandLineRunner {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MessageSenderApplication.class);
    private static final String QUEUE_NAME = "queue";

    @Autowired
    private JmsTemplate jmsTemplate;


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MessageSenderApplication.class, args);
    }

        @Override
        public void run (String...args){
            LOGGER.info("Sending message");
            jmsTemplate.convertAndSend(QUEUE_NAME, "Hello World");
        }

        @JmsListener(destination = QUEUE_NAME, containerFactory = "jmsListenerContainerFactory")
        public void receiveMessage (String message){
            LOGGER.info("Message received: {}", message);
        }
}
```

Exactly like in the tutorial.

I would appreciate the help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should create a bean in a @Configuration file, but receiving a factory as a parameter.

```
 @Bean
 public JmsTemplate jmsTemplate(ConnectionFactory jmsConnectionFactory) {
     JmsTemplate template = new JmsTemplate();
     template.setConnectionFactory(jmsConnectionFactory);
     template.setPubSubDomain(true); // false for a Queue, true for a Topic
     return template;
 }
```